# SwiftUI preview looks different from the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

Can anybody tell me why my views looks fine in the preview, but get pushed down in the simulator?  It's super simple and very little code so I honestly have no idea what's going on. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

struct MainView: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
   
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List {
            ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
               Text("Views go here")
               Text("Something else to track")
            } //: LOOP
            
         } //: LIST
         .navigationTitle("Track Stuff")
         .navigationBarItems(
            trailing: Button(action: {viewModel.signOut()}) {
               Text("Sign out")
                  .foregroundColor(buttonColor)
            }
         )
      } //: NAVIGATION
      .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
   }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      MainView()
   }
}
```

[image: Preview looks fine, but simulator has huge gap at top of screen]

Comment: Looks like you have nested NavigatonViews

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508175/andrew) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67557536/swiftui-preview-looks-different-than-simulator/67557607#comment119409850_67557536), the problem arose because I had nested NavigationViews.